# Match number with no decimal and greater than 10,000

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very familiar with regex and am trying to create a regex code in JavaScript to match a string with only

- whole numbers
- no decimals/dots
- and should be greater than 10,000

So far I have it like the ff. I think I am missing something as it still read through decimal numbers and == 10,000. How do I do that?

`[1-9](?!\.)\d[0-9]{3,}`

https://regex101.com/r/hG2iU7/61

Comment: Why use RexExp at all? It seems like a wrong choice here. JS has number-parsing licked already. Why not just [`parseFloat(theString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`Number(theString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) the entire string? It will fail/return `NaN` if it doesn't conform. You can then test it to ensure that it's an integral value less than 10000.

Comment: Can't you use anything other than regex? maybe parse to int then do some checks?

Comment: Thanks for you insight everyone! The bank I work with uses a particular form made by their in-house cms that strictly uses regex to check the inputs. That's why I'm limited to resort with regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
^[1-9][0-9]{4,}$
```

To exclude `10000` add a `(?!10000$)` lookahead:

```
^(?!10000$)[1-9][0-9]{4,}$
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tvPQ0/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%2C%7D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!10000$)` - a negative lookahead that cancels the match if the whole string is equal to `10000` (i.e. after start of string (`^`), there is `10000` and then end of string position follows (`$`))
- `[1-9]` - a digit from `1` to `9`
- `[0-9]{4,}` - any four or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What if it's greater than 99,999?

Comment: @briosheje The limiting quantifier should be `{4,}`, I fixed that

Comment: This will still match 10000, and doesn't check against dots.

Answer (score 7):

At the risk of not directly answering the question, JavaScript can already parse numbers. Why bother trying to reimplement this? Especially with RegExp?

Why not just [`parseFloat(theString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [`Number(theString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) the entire string?

It will fail/return `NaN` if what you have isn't a number, and you can test for this with [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

If it doesn't fail, you can then test it to ensure that it's an integral value:

```
const isIntegral = Math.trunc(theNumber) === theNumber;
```

and is less than 10000

```
const isLessThan10000 = theNumber < 10000;
```

This code is going to be ***much*** easier to read and maintain than a regular expression.

Comment: I agree with you entirely! This should likely be the better solution rather than resorting to regex. But like I said in my first comment in op, the bank I work with uses a particular form made by their in-house cms that strictly uses regex to check the inputs. That's why I'm limited to resort with regex